# Why does PowerShell ISE asks to confirm when an executable outputs to stderr?

Tags: powershell, stderr, powershell-ise

I am debugging a powershell script in ISE and there I call the sysinternals pskill utility.

For some reason, PowerShell opens the following dialog:

[image]

Why? How can I configure it not to show the dialog, but just run the script as I intend?

**EDIT 1**

The problem is reproduced very easily:

1. Run **ise -noprofile**
2. Inside ise command prompt run **pskill -h**

Here is the result:

[image]

Although, there is no dialog, but there is error output, which I suppose is the cause for the dialog in my other scenario. So, the question is what is the cause for the error output?

It seems that pskill sends part of its help screen to the stderr, indeed, observe:

```
C:\Dayforce\utils> .\pskill.exe -h

PsKill v1.15 - Terminates processes on local or remote systems
Copyright (C) 1999-2012  Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Usage: pskill [-t] [\\computer [-u username [-p password]]] <process ID | name>
     -t    Kill the process and its descendants.
     -u    Specifies optional user name for login to
           remote computer.
     -p    Specifies optional password for user name. If you omit this
           you will be prompted to enter a hidden password.

C:\Dayforce\utils> .\pskill.exe -h 2> $null
Usage: pskill [-t] [\\computer [-u username [-p password]]] <process ID | name>
     -t    Kill the process and its descendants.
     -u    Specifies optional user name for login to
           remote computer.
     -p    Specifies optional password for user name. If you omit this
           you will be prompted to enter a hidden password.

C:\Dayforce\utils>
```

So, it seems that I only had the problem with pskill, because it outputs to stderr and ISE considers it a good reason to open a dialog. I fix it with the -nobanner command line option.

But how to fix it in general? I do not want ISE to open any dialog if a command outputs stderr, which in itself may not be a good taste, but does not mean there is an error.

Comment: Add `-Confirm:$false ` to suppress command. `Set-PSDebug -Off`  [will turn off debugging features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-psdebug?view=powershell-6) .

Comment: What debugging features? I do want the ability to debug the script. Add `-Confirm:$false` where?

Answer (score 1):

In order to suppress the confirm box when you are using `Write-Debug` insert [this](https://learn-powershell.net/2014/06/01/prevent-write-debug-from-bugging-you/) at the top of your script / function :

```
If ($PSBoundParameters['Debug']) {
    $DebugPreference = 'Continue'
}
```

Comment: But I am not using Write-Debug. Let me post a minimal script that exhibits the described behavior.

Comment: But I guess your suggestion is going to eliminate the dialog, will check it.

Comment: I edited the question to focus on the real problem - dialog being open on any stderr.